# Suppose $A\subseteq{C}\And{B}\subseteq{D}$ Prove that: $A\times{B} = \left(A\times{D}\right)\cap\left(C\times{B}\right) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to approach it. So far I've come to this:
\begin{array}{|c|}
            \hline
            a\in{A}\rightarrow{}a\in{C} \\
            b\in{B}\rightarrow{}b\in{D} \\
            \hline
\end{array}
$$\left(x,y\right)\in \left(A\times{D}\right)\cap\left(C\times{B}\right)$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\left(x,y\right)\in\left(A\times{D}\right)\land\left(x,y\right)\in\left(C\times{B}\right)$$
$$\Downarrow $$
\begin{array}{c|c}
x\in{A} & x\in{C} \\
y\in{D} & y\in{B}
\end{array}
True
$$\Downarrow$$
$$A\times{B} = \left(A\times{D}\right)\cap\left(C\times{B}\right)$$
But I don't think it's correct at all.

Comment: It's one direction only and almost ok. You take $(x,y)$ from the right side. You obtain in particular that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. That would simply finish this direction. What about the other one?

Comment: @Berci something like :
$$\left(x,y\right) \in{A\times{B}}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$x\in{A}\land{}y\in{B}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $(a,\,b)\in A\times D\cap C\times B$ then $a\in A\cap C=A$ and $b\in B\cap D=B$, so $(a,\,b)\in A\times B$. On the other had, if $(a,\,b)\in A\times B$ then $(a,\,b)\in A\times D$ and $(a,\,b)\in C\times B$.

Comment: I think I understand it. Thank you!!